# Get the top row after order by in Oracle Subquery

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, limit

I have a table student(id, name, department, age, score). I want to find the youngest student who has the highest(among the youngest students) score of each department. In SQL Server, I can use following SQL.

```
select * from student s1 
where s1.id in 
(select s2.id from student s2 
where s2.department = s1.department order by age asc, score desc top 1).
```

However, in Oracle, you cannot use the order by clause in subquery and there is no limit/top like keyword. I have to join the student table with itself two times to query the result. In oracle, I use following SQL.

```
select s1.* from student s1, 
(select s2.department, s2.age, max(s2.score) as max_score from student s2, 
(select s3.department, min(s3.age) as min_age from student s3 group by s3.department) tmp1 where 
s2.department = tmp1.department and s2.age = tmp1.min_age group by s2.department, s2.age) tmp2 
where s1.department =tmp2.department and s1.age = tmp2.age and s1.score=tmp2.max_score
```

Does anyone have any idea to simplify the above SQL for oracle.

Comment: In Oracle, you *can* use the order by clause in a subquery.

Comment: There's a solution much simpler, without analytical functions, see the accepted answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180445/oracle-left-join-very-big-table-and-limit-the-joined-rows-to-one-with-the-large

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this one

```
select * from
  (SELECT id, name, department, age, score,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by department order by age desc, score asc) srlno 
  FROM student) 
where srlno = 1;
```

Comment: I had similar scenario, thought to handle using pl/sql block, but your solution worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Allan's answer, this works fine too:

```
select * 
from (SELECT * 
  FROM student
  order by age asc, 
           score desc) 
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: This returns just the top row of "all" results. That might match to the question title. But the question actually asks the top row of "each department". That's why it's simpler than Bharat's answers.

Comment: That's true Protron, I actually missed that distinction, and answered a simpler question, which was actually what I was looking for myself when I googled for and found this thread. So I suppose all the answers are correct and useful, depending on what the reader is actually looking for.  For my purpose, Allan's answer was the most useful, and then I refined it and reposted. For your purpose, Bharat's answer is the most useful.  Everyone wins! (Although, I've noted Allan has edited his answer due to your prompting, but I'll leave mine as is, as it is a perfect answer for many people).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Bharat's answer, it is possible to do this using ORDER BY in the sub-query in Oracle (as point out by Jeffrey Kemp):

```
SELECT *
FROM   student s1
WHERE  s1.id IN (SELECT id
                 FROM   (SELECT   id, ROWNUM AS rn
                         FROM     student s2
                         WHERE    s1.department = s2.department
                         ORDER BY age ASC, score DESC)
                 WHERE  rn = 1);
```

If you use this method, you may be tempted to remove the sub-query and just use `rownum = 1`. This would result in the incorrect result as the sort would be applied after the criteria (you'd get 1 row that was sorted, not one row from the sorted set).

Comment: The question actually asks the top row of "each department". You are not using the deparment to group the results. Probably this answer is useful for people looking into similar questions to the title without reading the question content. But I want to point out the difference for people comparing solutions (because they won't get the same results).

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(job_trigger_time,'mm-dd-yyyy') ,job_status from
(select * from kdyer.job_instances ji INNER JOIN kdyer.job_param_values pm 
on((ji.job_id = pm.job_id) and (ji.job_spec_id = '10003') and (pm.param_value='21692') )
order by ji.job_trigger_time desc)
where rownum<'2'
```