# SQL - Join up to N rows per match

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I have a one-to-many relationship and want to join two tables on some JOIN_ID, but for each distinct JOIN_ID I would like to limit the number of rows in the result to n.  How would I do this?

*Oracle SQL

Comment: Please tag your question with your RDBMS. e.g. mysql, sql server, postgres, teradata etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit the number of rows returned by this LEFT JOIN to one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236229/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-this-left-join-to-one) - limiting it to one is almost identical to limiting it to 2, 3, 4, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by joinkey order by ??) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.joinkey = t2.joinkey and seqnum <= 6;
```

The `??` is for specifying the ordering to define the rows you want to key.  For instance, `order by id desc` would keep the rows with the highest ids.

Comment: This appears to be very inefficient, will open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS supports `row_number()` then you could do something like this:

```
select *
from (
  select 
      t1.*
    , t2.*
    , row_number() over (partition by t1.join_id order by t2.id) as rn
  from t1
    inner join t2
      on t1.join_id = t2.join_id
  ) as s
where rn < 6
```